# Convert Image to binary stream

Tags: python, django, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

There are two sides to my app, on one side I'm using C++ in order to read the frames from a camera using Pleora's EBUS SDK. When this stream is first received, before I convert the buffer to an image, I am able to read the stream 16 bits at a time in order to perform some calculations for each pixel, i.e. there exists a 16 bit chunk of data for each pixel.

Now the second half is a Django web app where I am also presented this video output, this time via an ffmpeg, nginx, hls stream. When the user clicks on the video I want to be able to take the current frame and the coordinates of their click and perform the same calculation as I do above in the C++ portion.

Right now I use an html5 canvas to capture the frame and I use `canvas.toDataURL()` in order to convert the frame into a base64 encoded image, I then pass the base64 image, the coordinates, and the dimensions of the frame to python via AJAX.

In python I am trying to manipulate this base64 encoded image in such a way as to get 16 bits per pixel. At the moment I do the following:

```
pos = json.loads(request.GET['pos'])
str_frame = json.loads(request.GET['frame'])
dimensions = json.loads(request.GET['dimensions'])

pixel_index = (dimensions['width'] * pos['y']) + pos['x'] + 1

b64decoded_frame = base64.b64decode(str_frame.encode('utf-8'))
```

However, there are far fewer indexes in the `b64decoded_frame` then there are pixels in the image and the integer values aren't nearly as high as expected. I have checked and the image is intact as I am able to save it as a png.

To summarize, how do I convert a base64 image into a serialized binary stream where each pixel is represented by 16 bits.

**UPDATE**

I forgot to mention that I'm using python3.2

And after some more research I *think* that what I'm trying to do it get the mono16 value of a given pixel. I don't know for sure if that is what I want to do but if anyone could explain how to either convert an image to mono16 or a pixel to mono16 I could explore that and see if it is in fact the solution.

Comment: why are you encoding to `utf-8` before `b64decode`?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm using python3 and if I don't do that I gives a type error "expected bytes not str". By encoding it as utf-8 it ensures that it is a bytes object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I've chosen is to convert the image into an 8-bit greyscale image then convert the desired pixel into its 16-bit counterpart. The solution looks like the following:

```
import base64
import io
from PIL import Image

if request.method == 'GET':
    if request.GET['pos'] and request.GET['frame']:
        pos = json.loads(request.GET['pos'])
        str_frame = json.loads(request.GET['frame'])

        # Converts the base64 string into a byte string, we need to encode
        # str_frame as utf-8 first otherwise python3.2 complains about unicode
        b64decoded_frame = base64.b64decode(str_frame.encode('utf-8'))

        # This puts the decoded image into a buffer so that I don't need to save
        # it to disk to use it in PIL
        byte_stream = io.BytesIO(b64decoded_frame)

        # Open the image and convert it to 8-bit greyscale (mono8)
        img = Image.open(byte_stream).convert('L')

        # Get the 8-bit pixel value
        pixel_val = img.getpixel((pos['x'], pos['y']))

        # Convert the 8-bit pixel value to 16-bit by holding the rations
        # i.e. n8 / (2^8 - 1) == x16 / (2^16 - 1)
        pixel_val = int(pixel_val / 255 * 65535)
```