# Image to matrix in python

Tags: opencv, numpy, image-processing, scipy, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to convert an image into a matrix.

```
values = []
normal = []
for x in (arr):
    for y in (arr):
        if arr[x,y] > 1:
            normal.append(1)
        else:
            normal.append(0)
```

And error says:

> "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `arr` is a 2d array. 
If you want to use `x, y` as index and `arr` is a 2d array then try this:

```
m, n = arr.shape
for x in range(m):
    for y in range(n):
        if arr[x,y] > 1:
            normal.append(1)
        else:
            normal.append(0)
```

However the code doesn't look pythonic. I would use `numpy.where` but it is hard to help without knowing what you really want to do.

Comment: thanks for the help, im really new to image processing in python so, can you give me an example where it converts the image into binary matrix?

Comment: Take a look at these threads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23225738/convert-image-to-binary-stream and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22351254/python-script-to-convert-image-into-byte-array Are you trying to do the same thing?

Comment: this is from your second comments, yes although I don't understand the first link